# How to play Minecraft with a PS3 Sixaxis controller on Ubuntu?

Tags: games, minecraft, ps3

I originally posted this on another StackExchange site, Arqade, but I've had no luck there, so I've deleted it there in order to ask it somewhere with more Ubuntu specific knowledge.

Here's the what I originally wrote on Arqade:

> I would really love to be able to play Minecraft on my Ubuntu laptop
>   with my Sixaxis. While I've experimented with Sixad I didn't really
>   know what I was doing and I couldn't get Minecraft to recognise the
>   Sixaxis buttons as inputs. Can anyone give me a step-by-step guide to
>   getting it to work?

Basically, I got my PS3 controller connected to my laptop by bluetooth and I was able to control the computer with it; move mouse, scroll, move mouse with gyroscope etc., but I couldn't get Minecraft to recognise the PS3 controller's outputs as inputs. So yeah, can anyone give me a step-by-step guide?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 on a HP Folio 13.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Tried again today. It's become worse. I can connect the SIXAXIS to the computer with sixpair and sixad etc. but now the computer is not recognising *any* inputs. I can't move the mouse with the joystick any more, for example. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you go to the Ubuntu help community. They have an excellent help guide. Here's the link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sixaxis Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Qjoypad. Once you have your pad bluetoothed to your machine proper just use Qjoy to map the keyboard keys/mouse movement/keys to the pad as you desire. Also, make sure you don't have ibus-daemon running or no keystrokes will get sent to the game, this includes Qjoy-mapped keys on your gamepad. I would suggest installing the [Control Pack](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/355537-162-controlpack-autosneakrunautotoolsmartfurnacelookbehindlots-more-v510/) mod as it makes the game played with a pad a lot easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is the Catch: I have not got it perfect yet, but I am able to use it.

I searched to Profiles till I found one that is close to the one required for MINECRAFT.

I am unable to "At this time" get Qtsixa to recognize profile changes, Therefore I just changed to profile settings within Minecraft to Match the predetermined key in Qtsixa.

As you said you can get it running, but it will not recognize the analogue within Minecraft. I just changed the Profile to KDE or better yet super Mario Chronicles.